# Inherited jquery Ajax asynchronous call in loop

Tags: jquery

I have created inherited ajax call in loop i need which give unexpected output if async have made "true" to overcome this issue I have made the call synchronous ,
Is there any method that we can wait for the inherited calls to complete then proceed to the next iteration .
I am attaching code snipplets as given below.

In the below code i have use 2 synchronous call i  need to convert those call to asynchronous please suggest me any solution.

```
/// Main Loop

 $.each(AllStagesvgdata, function (idx, svgdata) {
             baseimageaspectratio = 1;
            svgEditor.changeZoomManualFluid(0);
            ///process stages and controls
            ParseStageControlsDynamic(svgdata.Id);
            var filename = '';

            var svginf = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n" + svgCanvas.getSvgString();
            ///process png image creation
            ProcessSvgImageFiledynamic(svgdata.Id, filename, svginf);

      });


///function to Create png files and html pages
function ProcessSvgImageFiledynamic(stageid, filename, svginf) {
    var bbbox = "";
    try {

        var groupLayer_new = $("#svgcontent")[0]; //.find("#groupLayer_new")[0];
        var bb = groupLayer_new.getBBox();
        if (bb != null && bb.width != 0) {
            bbbox = "" + bb.x + "," + bb.y + "," + bb.width + "," + bb.height;
        }
    }
    catch (e) { }
    $("#loadingnew").show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/FrontEndPlan/PngFileSaveFluid",   // change to full path of file on server
        data: { "svgdata": svginf, "pngfilename": filename, "boundbox": bbbox },
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#loadingnew").show();
            printimgcount++;
            if ($(AllStageImages).find("Plan > Stage[Id='" + stageid + "']").length > 0) {
                $(AllStageImages).find("Plan > Stage[Id='" + stageid + "']").attr({ "ImageFileName": msg.filename, "ImageSrc": msg.fullfilename });
            }
            ///check all the stages have been processed
            if (AllStagesvgdata.length == printimgcount) {
            ///Create the html pages when all the svg data have been processed
                CreateHtmlPagesForPrintPlan();
            $("#loadingnew").hide(); }

        },
        error: function () { }
    });

}


function ParseStageControlsDynamic(newtargetstageid) {
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/FrontEndPlan/GetResponseText",
            data: { url: encodeURI(decodeURI(baseimage.attr("SRC").substr(0, 1) == "/" ? imgsrclocal + baseimage.attr("SRC") : baseimage.attr("SRC"))) + "?&ms=" + mytime },
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            success: function (svgstringeval) {
                svgCanvas.importSvgStringparentnode(svgstringeval, groupLayer_new, grouplayerdragged, 'baseimage_svg', '0');

                $(AllStageXmlList).find("Plan > Stage[Id='" + newtargetstageid + "'] > Control").each(function () {
                    $("#loadingnew").show();

                    RuleImplemetationDynamic(newtargetstageid, $(this).attr("Title"));
                });

            },
            error: function (data, status, e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        });
}




///Function for rule implementation
function RuleImplemetationDynamic(stageid, controltile) {

    $("#loadingnew").show();
    $(AllStageXmlList).find("Plan > Stage[Id='" + stageid + "'] > Control[Title='" + controltile + "'] > ControlImage").each(function () {

        if ($(this).attr("ImageInclude") == "true") {
            AfterRuleImplementDynamic($(this).attr("ControlImageId"), stageid, controltile, true);
        }
        else {
            AfterRuleImplementDynamic($(this).attr("ControlImageId"), stageid, controltile, false);
        }


    });

    $("#loadingnew").hide();



}
///End of Function for rule implementation


//Function to add image after rule read to the svg canvas
function AfterRuleImplementDynamic(id, targetstage, targetcontrol, shouldinclude) {
 var mytime = new Date().getTime();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    async: false,
                    url: "/FrontEndPlan/GetResponseText",
                    data: { url: encodeURI(decodeURI(imgsrc)) + "?&ms=" + mytime },

                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (svgstringeval) {

                        svgCanvas.importSvgStringparentnode(svgstringeval, groupLayer_new, grouplayerdragged, "layerimage_" + controlid, '1');

                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: You are asking for a synchronous behaviour using async requests in a single thread language as javascript is, right? I cannot see a way of doing this without freezing UI. You could still look at $.when() if it can help you. Other way could be "Web Workers" but only in HTML5.

Comment: I have tried the $.when() , $.Differed() , promise(), done(), but none of them gave me any desired result also for the "Web Workers" it will not work on all browsers thus this is also not any perfect solution.